# bundler complains about unfilled dependency version but there is no such entry in Gemfile

Tags: bundler, gemfile

In both, the Gemfile and in Gemfile.lock there's nothing about oauth2 (=0.5.0) , both are set to 0.4.1

Where is this dependency written?

Here's end of output from bundle install

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "oauth2":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    oauth2 (0.4.1)

  In Gemfile:
    diaspora-client depends on
      oauth2 (= 0.5.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before, for my case, i just reinstall everything using a network where there is no firewall or any restriction. Previously i use a network with alot of restriction, then it keep give me error. After I change network, all work perfectly fine.